# Problems with binding on kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Im following a kivy tutorial *(http://inclem.net/pages/kivy-crash-course/)* and im having problems in lesson 004 *(http://inclem.net/2019/12/18/kivy/kivy_tutorial_004_event_bindings/)* where they teach about binding buttons (of a calculator in this case) to do things (display things you type).

They say to write this inside the build function

```
def print_button_text(self, instance):
    print(instance.text)
for button in button_grid.children[1:]:
    button.bind(on_press=print_button_text)

# we could also have used `button.bind(on_press=lambda instance: print(instance.text))
```

And it was supposed to print in console the numbers we press. But it doesn't work.

An TypeError exception occurs saying print_buton_text() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance'

I've tried defining the function before and using a lambda (as it says in the comment). I've not tried anything else because I dont know what to try.

And by the way, I'm using an android compiler: pydroid 3. It may have something to do with the error...

Hope someone can help me.

Here is all the code I have:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class YourApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root_widget = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

        output_label = Label(size_hint_y=1)

        button_symbols = ('1', '2', '3', '+',
                          '4', '5', '6', '-',
                          '7', '8', '9', '.',
                          '0', '*', '/', '=')

        button_grid = GridLayout(cols=4, size_hint_y=2)
        for symbol in button_symbols:
            button_grid.add_widget(Button(text=symbol))

        clear_button = Button(text='clear', size_hint_y=None,
                              height=100)

        root_widget.add_widget(output_label)
        root_widget.add_widget(button_grid)
        root_widget.add_widget(clear_button)
            
        def print_button_text(self, instance):
            output_label.text += instance.text
        for button in button_grid.children[1:]:
            button.bind(on_press=print_button_text)
        
        return root_widget


YourApp().run()
```

Comment: `def print_button_text` should be defined outside `build` function

Answer (score 0):

```
    def print_button_text(self, instance):
        output_label.text += instance.text
```

The example is incorrect, it should read as follows (i.e. without the `self` argument as this function is standalone and not a class method):

```
    def print_button_text(instance):
        output_label.text += instance.text
```

I've corrected the version at http://inclem.net/2019/12/18/kivy/kivy_tutorial_004_event_bindings/